# Reflect a shape in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

Is there a neat way to reflect the parallelogram below to keep the base CB the same but create the two new points EF like the diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(-1,3){A}
\tkzDefParallelogram(B,C,A) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzDrawPolygon(B,C,A,D)

\tkzLabelPoints(C,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A,D)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,...,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(-1,3){A}
\tkzDefParallelogram(A,B,C) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=.75](C,D)\tkzGetPoint{G}
\tkzInterLL(A,D)(B,G) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzDefParallelogram(E,B,C) \tkzGetPoint{F}
\tkzDrawSegment(D,E)
\tkzDrawPolygons(A,B,C,D B,C,F,E)
\tkzLabelPoints(B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A,D,E,F)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](G)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,...,G)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]